# ERROR: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:45: unexpected token : DESC on fetching the last record from the table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I am trying to fetch the last record from the database using the below hibernate query

```
//fetch the last data from a field in a table
Session session = _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("select t.currentfile from file t DESC");
query.setMaxResults(1);
List<Object[]> rows = query.list();

for (Object[] row: rows) {
    System.out.println(" ------------------- ");
    System.out.println("current file: " + row[0]);
}
```

with the above hql I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:45: unexpected token
: DESC
```

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descending ('DESC' or 'desc') and Ascending ('ASC' or 'asc') can only be used with an **order by** clause.

So your code would have to look something like:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select t.currentfile from file t 
  ORDER BY t.time_created DESC");
```

(`time_created` is only an example field as you have not added what fields you have in your table or what you are ordering by in descending order)

Comment: will this give me the latest data in the currentfile column

Comment: Okay I am having this issue unable to resolve path t.currentfile. unexpected token t

Comment: cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong. You have to put an ORDER BY yourSortAttribute before the DESC.

Comment: The entity's field you want to sort. DESC means descending order. If you don't want the results to be sorted just remove DESC.

Comment: session.createQuery("select t.currentfile from file order by t DESC");

Comment: You mean the latest entry from the table? Then please post what your table and entity look like.

Comment: I have a table called file with a field called current file

Comment: You have to add an attribute. Like
   
session.createQuery("select t.currentfile from file order by t.currentFile DESC");

Comment: I want to get the latest data in currentfile column

Comment: So please add your table definition and your entity code. How would you identify the "latest value in column"? By id?